# Render a partial based on a condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I want to render a template base on a condition, however I'm getting a missing template error:

```
Missing partial template/default_template with {:locale=>[:es], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
```

**Method:**

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def select_template_for(analysis)
     special_templates = %w(cat dog)
     selected_template = special_templates.find { |tpl| tpl == analysis } || 'default_template'
     puts selected_template
     render "template/#{selected_template}"
   end  
end
```

**View:**

```
<%= select_template_for(@result.id_analysis) %>
```

folder structure:

```
pets
  show (where the helper is called)
  template
     _cat.html.erb
     _dog.html.erb
     _default_template.html.erb
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try `render "pets/template/<template_name>"`

example:

```
def render_template_for(type)
  partials = %w(cat dog)
  partial = partials.include?(type) ? type : 'default_template'

  render "pets/template/#{partial}"
end
```

or even:

```
def render_template_for(type)
  partial = %w(cat dog) & [type]
  render "pets/template/#{partial[0] || 'default_template'}"
end
```

and:

```
def render_template_for(type)
  partial = %w(cat dog).delete type
  render "pets/template/#{partial || 'default_template'}"
end
```

Comment: Would have been my guess also.

Comment: Except: not underscore template "_template_name" but rather render "pets/template/<template_name>"

Comment: it's just mistake, also you could rename `select_template_for` to `render_template_for` (looks better, because you not just select template but render it too)

Answer (score 1):

In addition of ISO4's answer, as per your method name, move your `render` statement out of the helper method to `view`

**Method:**

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def select_template_for(analysis)
     special_templates = %w(cat dog)
     special_templates.find { |tpl| tpl == analysis } || 'default_template'
  end  
end
```

**View:**

```
render "pets/template/#{select_template_for(@result.id_analysis)}"
```

Comment: Or, as IS04 pointed out, rename the method to "render_template_for"